# Escape a star (*) character in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I just cant do it. If * is in a variable, it expands to a list of files in current folder. echo "*" works fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
c="GRANT ALL ON \*.* TO '$1'@'localhost';"
mysql < $c
exit 0;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use single quotes for your string:

```
c='GRANT ALL ON *.* TO';
c="${c} '$1'@'localhost';";
```

There is probably a better way to do that but including $1 in the string made it weird

Comment: This isn't the problem at all -- wildcards don't get expanded inside double-quotes either, so (other than removing the backslash) this is the same as what the question had.  The real problem is how `c` is used, not how it's defined.  See Gilles, slillibri, and Dennis Williamson's answers for more relevant solutions.

Answer (score 10):

1. Always put double quotes around variable substitutions, otherwise characters like spaces and `*` appearing in the value are interpreted by the shell. I.e., write `"$c"`, not `$c`.
2. The syntax `mysql <"$c"` makes `mysql` execute commands from a file whose name is the value of `$c`. What you're looking for is

   ```
   printf '%s\n' "$c" | mysql
   ```

   or simpler, as long as you remember the restrictions (`$c` must not start with a `-`, and if it contains `\` that's ok in bash but not in some other variants of sh)

   ```
   echo "$c" | mysql
   ```

   There's another alternative that's more comfortable if the command is multiline. It's called a “here-document”. The string `EOF` isn't special (though it's traditional), any sequence of letters and digits will do. The terminating `EOF` may *not* be preceded by whitespace. You need to put a `\` before every `$`, `\` and `` ` `` unless you want them interpreted by the shell.

   ```
   mysql <<EOF
   GRANT ALL ON *.* TO '$1'@'localhost';
   EOF
   ```
3. Beware that if the argument to the shell contains a single quote, you have an injection vector. The following snippet adds a `\` before every `\` and `'`.

   ```
   set -- "${1//\\/\\\\}"
   set -- "${1//\'/\'}"
   ```

   This is fairly ugly, which is why if you're going to do anything complicated, forget about using a shell and use a language with actual SQL bindings (perl, python, whatever) where the library handles all the quoting and procedure building for you.

Answer (score 2):

This will work in bash, no escaping necessary

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u root -e "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO '$1'@'localhost'"
exit 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to **print** the SQL command using echo.

Then you need to put **quotes** around `$c` like so:

```
mysql <( echo "$c" )
```

Otherwise the value of `$c` will be treated as a bash command and thus, the `*` will be expanded.

Or a simpler version could be:

```
mysql -e "$c"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's no more complicated than this:

```
#!/bin/bash
c="GRANT ALL ON *.* TO $1@localhost;"
mysql -e "$c"
```

Or, if you need the single quotes:

```
#!/bin/bash
c="GRANT ALL ON *.* TO '$1'@'localhost';"
mysql -e "$c"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple is perfect! (quote the first part with single quote)

```
#!/bin/bash
c='GRANT ALL ON *.*' "TO '$1'@'localhost';"
mysql < $c
exit 0;
```

it should be perfect too! ($c quoted)

```
#!/bin/bash
c="GRANT ALL ON *.* TO '$1'@'localhost';"
mysql < "$c"
exit 0;
```

Comment: Will this not treat $c as a file name

Answer (score 0):

The feature fighting you is shell globbing as part of pathname expansion.  Disable this to solve the primary problem you reported.  Then use Weboide's suggestion of -e to execute a single command contained in the $c variable through Mysql.  Cheers,

```
[maxwell@elite ~]$ cat me.sh
#!/bin/bash

# disable shell globbing so c variable can be literal
set -f
c="GRANT ALL ON *.* TO '$1'@'localhost';"

echo $c

# enable shell globbing for normal operation
set +f
echo $c
[maxwell@elite ~]$ ./me.sh maxwell
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'maxwell'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL ON labserver.etc.0710.tar me.sh Validation.txt TO 'maxwell'@'localhost';
[maxwell@elite ~]$
```